# Why is inline code blocked by CSP on localhost:8080

Tags: javascript, localhost, content-security-policy

Using Delphi Indy HTTP server components. Operational server works fine with HTTPS. I use a development server on a remote machine via localhost:8080. That works very well also.
Now I have copied all code and support files to my local PC and testing via localhost:8080 fails due to CSP blocking of inline event handlers.
I have two questions: a) why would there be CSP blocking on the local PC while there is none on the remote development machine. b) how can I overcome the CSP blocking on localhost:8080?

The server generates a start page with !DOCTYPE html. On the remote machine there is no CSP meta tag. On the PC I have tried several specifications, like

> meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
>   script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self'
>   'unsafe-inline'; img-src *;">

None of these work. Problems arise with tags with an inline event handler, like *onchange="relay(event)"* and 'unsafe' functions like *setTimeout("xxx")*.
I will modify these function calls. But changing the inline event handlers is cumbersome. And it seems an overkill for testing on a local machine. NB: all resources are local; tested with Edged and Chrome.

Comment: setup a demo neither on github or jsfiddle which can help us reproduce.